# use case OR in financial service industry

Tags: optimization, finance, operations

What are some use cases, with high dollar value impact, of OR and optimization in the financial services industry like life insurance, annuity business?

I have seen common use cases of queuing theory for call center, generalized assignment problem, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in this [book](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/gc0v/webpub/book.pdf) several problems that you search.

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, great link.

Answer (score 0):

[Portfolio optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portfolio_optimization) seems to use mathematical programming extensively. Whether is has "high dollar value impact" probably depends on the size of the portfolio you are optimizing.